# FormKit inputs inside Dynamic Component Error : [plugin:vite-plugin-vue-inspector] Invalid end tag

Tags: nuxt.js, formkit

I am trying to use Formkit inside a dynamically rendered component :

Sheet.vue -> ResourceForm.vue -> <>/Form.vue

```
// script section from ResourceForm.vue
const formComponent = defineAsyncComponent(() => {
  try {
    if (!props.formSlug) throw new Error("No Component Directory");
    return import(`./${props.formSlug}/Form.vue`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
});

// template section from ResourceForm.vue
<component :is="formComponent" />

// Form.vue

<script setup lang="ts">
const sample = 3;
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <FormKit name="test" label="test" placeholder="test" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Error is :

```
[plugin:vite-plugin-vue-inspector] Invalid end tag.
/home/joojieman/nsp-six/web-client/components/product_categories/Form.vue
```